# From iPhone Camera To Remote Server, Real-Time Streamming

Tags: ios, videochat

Im developing an iOS App that ideally will provide a video chat functionality

Currently i've managed to make it work inside a wifi network, using AVCaptureOutput, Bonjour, NSNetServices, CFSocketStreams and NSStreams. Having 2 iOS devices (client and server) connected to the same wifi.

What i want to achieve is having the connection over my dedicated server, and not over a local wifi network. So the 2 or more devices can use 3G as well, LTE and so forth.

I would like to know how i can stream the camera FROM my iPhone TO my remote dedicated server.
I DON'T want to use Wowza as a server, i DON'T want OpenTok or similar tools, i DON'T want HTTP Live Streaming tools from Apple (they're tools for the "SERVER TO IOS and NOT IOS TO SERVER", and they are for media stream only, not real-time camera/mic)

I've also read about CFHTTP requests, NSURLConnections, JSON and HTML5 but i still don't know how they work, or if they are what i need.

Summarizing:

How it's possible to stablish a connection between my iPhone with my remote dedicated Server, and stream the iPhone camera/mic constantly at 30fps in real-time?

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (camera, real-time, steram, server) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is that Apple doesn't provide a way to do that in iOS - they simply do not offer a direct way to get at the hardware-encoded frames to send out. The longer answer is that you can, but you have to be savvy about iteratively packetizing and sending short segments of to-file hardware-encoded video, and over your preferred protocol.

Once you solve the packetization of hardware encoded frames issue, you have to solve the replication issue (client -> server -> [multiple subscribers]). Since you don't want to use Wowza, and by your intonation, seemingly don't want to use any server that you didn't write, you probably should read up on RTMP and RTSP as you write your own. I can't imagine a situation where I'd want to write my own RTMP server, but I won't judge you. ;-)

Note: I've done exactly what you (seemingly) are trying to do, doing exactly what I described in the first paragraph. I *did* use RTMP as the streaming protocol, and packetized short segments of h.264 hardware encoded files onto the stream. What I didn't write myself was the replication of the stream to end clients from the server. Use Wowza. Or nginx-rtmp. Or FMS. Anything -- if you really want to write your own, that's your prerogative, but honestly: don't.